# NSToolbar with NSView subclass custom view does not render in customise toolbar panel

Tags: macos, appkit, programmatically-created, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I have created some `NSToolbarItem`s programmatically with custom views in an AppKit app. The toolbar items are appearing (and functioning) just fine in the toolbar. The issue arises when the toolbar is being customised.

The `NSToolbarItem` with `NSView`-subclass custom view does render in toolbar and the *"... or drag the default set into the toolbar"* area of the customisation panel (the bottom bit), but not in the *"Drag your favourite items into the toolbar ..."* area of the customisation panel (the top bit). The same code generates all 3 `NSToolbarItem` instances.

Toolbar items using `NSButton`, `NSTextField` and other controls as custom views do render in all case, but not those based on `NSView`. What do I need to do to make `NSView`-based custom toolbar items visible in both areas of the customise toolbar pane?

[image]

Here's a cut-down version of the `NSWindowController` which creates the toolbar (and acts as the toolbar's delegate)

```swift
import AppKit

public class DocumentWindowController : NSWindowController, NSToolbarDelegate {
    
    private struct ToolbarItemIdentifiers {
        fileprivate static let addPhotos = NSToolbarItem.Identifier("add-photos")
        fileprivate static let thumbnailSize = NSToolbarItem.Identifier("thumbnail-size")
    }
    
    public override init (
        window: NSWindow?
    ) {
        super.init(window: window)

        let toolbar = NSToolbar(identifier: "toolbar-identifier.document")
        toolbar.delegate = self
        toolbar.allowsUserCustomization = true
        toolbar.autosavesConfiguration = true
        toolbar.displayMode = .default
        window?.toolbarStyle = .unified
        window?.titleVisibility = .visible
        window?.toolbar = toolbar
    }
    
    // MARK: - NSToolbarDelegate
    
    public func toolbar (
        _ toolbar: NSToolbar,
        itemForItemIdentifier itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier,
        willBeInsertedIntoToolbar flag: Bool
    ) -> NSToolbarItem? {
        switch itemIdentifier {
            case ToolbarItemIdentifiers.addPhotos:
                let toolbarItem = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)
                toolbarItem.label = "Add Photos"
                toolbarItem.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "plus", accessibilityDescription: "Add Photos Icon")
                toolbarItem.target = self
                toolbarItem.action = #selector(self.addPhotosButtonTapped)
                return toolbarItem
            case ToolbarItemIdentifiers.thumbnailSize:
                let toolbarItem = NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)
                toolbarItem.label = "Thumbnail Size"
                toolbarItem.view = ThumbnailSizeView() // an unremarkable NSView subclass
                return toolbarItem
            default:
                return nil
        }
    }
    
    public func toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers (_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {
        return [
            ToolbarItemIdentifiers.addPhotos,
            ToolbarItemIdentifiers.thumbnailSize
        ]
    }
    
    public func toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers (_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {
        return [
            ToolbarItemIdentifiers.addPhotos,
            ToolbarItemIdentifiers.thumbnailSize
        ]
    }
}

class ThumbnailSizeView : NSView {
    
    private let slider = NSSlider()
    
    init(min minValue: Int64, max maxValue: Int64, initial initialValue: Int64) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        let minusIcon = NSImageView()
        minusIcon.image = NSImage(
            systemSymbolName: "minus",
            accessibilityDescription: "Smaller"
        )?.withSymbolConfiguration(.init(scale: .small))
        minusIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        minusIcon.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        minusIcon.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        addSubview(minusIcon)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            minusIcon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            minusIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)
        ])
        
        slider.minValue = Double(minValue)
        slider.maxValue = Double(maxValue)
        slider.intValue = Int32(initialValue)
        slider.sliderType = .linear
        slider.controlSize = .mini
        slider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(slider)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: minusIcon.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),
            slider.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 66)
        ])
        
        let plusIcon = NSImageView()
        plusIcon.image = NSImage(
            systemSymbolName: "plus",
            accessibilityDescription: "Larger"
        )?.withSymbolConfiguration(.init(scale: .small))
        plusIcon.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        plusIcon.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        plusIcon.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        addSubview(plusIcon)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            plusIcon.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: slider.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),
            plusIcon.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
            plusIcon.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

For context, I'm using Xcode 14.3.1 on macOS Ventura 13.5.1

Comment: Post the relevant `ThumbnailSizeView` code please.

Comment: @Willeke I have added the `ThumbnailSizeView` code as requested

Comment: The `ThumbnailSizeView` is missing a height constraint.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick @Willeke. If you put your comment in answer form, I'm happy to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ThumbnailSizeView` is missing a height constraint and its height is zero. Add a height constraint to fix the issue.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    slider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: minusIcon.trailingAnchor, constant: 4),
    slider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor),
    slider.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 66)
])
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem not long ago ... I THINK the fix in my case was to not always return a new NSToolbarItem in toolbar:itemForItemIdentifier:willBeInsertedIntoToolbar: but to cache them based on the identifier and always return the same one. The copies for the customisation panel are created internally in some other way ...

Comment: Maybe try - but how it fix not render the toolbox?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Yansen13, but this seems to go directly against Apple's advice in `NSToolbarDelegate.toolbar(_:itemForItemIdentifier:willBeInsertedIntoToolbar:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbardelegate/1516985-toolbar): _"Don’t recycle toolbar items; always provide a new instance, even if the toolbar previously asked for an item with the same identifier"_.